# Why ParNew in CMS Final Remark, and sys time is so long?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

Recently my server Full GC is often very long (about 1 sec). I find that ParNew GC is in CMS Final Remark period. And sys time of ParNew is often very long. As far as my know sys time is kernel mode use time(eg: io), but this server use swap is zero at that time. Can anyone explain it?

```
2019-12-07T09:49:42.644+0800: 54818.811: [GC (CMS Final Remark) [YG occupancy: 1044459 K (2048000 K)]2019-12-07T09:49:42.645+0800: 54818.812: [GC (CMS Final Remark) 2019-12-07T09:49:42.648+0800: 54818.815: [ParNew: 1044459K->47633K(2048000K), 0.8381239 secs] 4333652K->3341991K(6144000K), 0.8445423 secs] [Times: user=0.35 sys=0.83, real=0.85 secs] 
2019-12-07T09:49:43.491+0800: 54819.658: [Rescan (parallel) , 0.0302395 secs]2019-12-07T09:49:43.522+0800: 54819.688: [weak refs processing, 0.0067316 secs]2019-12-07T09:49:43.528+0800: 54819.695: [class unloading, 0.0801524 secs]2019-12-07T09:49:43.608+0800: 54819.775: [scrub symbol table, 0.0134738 secs]2019-12-07T09:49:43.622+0800: 54819.789: [scrub string table, 0.0034579 secs][1 CMS-remark: 3294357K(4096000K)] 3341991K(6144000K), 0.9888975 secs] [Times: user=0.69 sys=0.85, real=0.99 secs]
```

Comment: Please spend some time correctly tagging your question. Then experts on that topic will also be able to find your question.

Answer (score 0):

That might be due to other kernel tasks such as physical page defragmentation (either for THPs or NUMA optimization). The number only gives you a starting point where to investigate, it doesn't point at a specific cause. You could try looking at kernel statistics or sampling your application + kernel stacks with `perf` to investigate further.

Sidenote: Rescan is not a Full GC, it's part of the CMS old generation GC cycle. Full GCs only happen as a fallback measure.